# What's the correct way of installing MySQL on CentOS 6.6 on Compute Engine by Google?

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, centos6

I've been trying to install MySQL on CentOS 6.6 but with no good results. I have just created a new VM with these steps:

1.- sudo yum -y install mysql-server mysql
2.- sudo mysql -u root
**RESULT** .- **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

also doing a "sudo service mysql start"
**RESULT** mysql: unrecognized service

Thanks mates !

Comment: Try `sudo service mysqld start` (note the `d` at the end of `mysqld`) before step 2.

Comment: @MishaBrukman "sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start" did work, thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

or

```
 sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: Dude, let me tell you that you are a genius... Thanks bro ! :)